# User Defaults (NSUserDefaults) Not Saving in Simulator Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save a high score for a game that I am making. When running the simulator the high score works but when I run the app again the high score resets.

The code I am using looks something like this.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var score = Double() // score is established during gameplay
var theHighScore = Double()

func highScoreKeeper(){
defaults.setDouble(score, forKey: "highScore")
let highScore = defaults.doubleForKey("highScore")
defaults.synchronize()
theHighScore = highScore
println(theHighScore)
println(defaults.doubleForKey("highScore"))
}
```

Both println statements print the same (correct) high score for that session, but once the simulator is reset, the high score resets. Is there a problem with the code? Or is this how the simulator acts always? If the latter is the case, is there any way I can test the high score keeper to confirm that it works properly?

Comment: All you need is to add a condition to check if score  >  defaults.doubleForKey("highScore") before saving it

Comment: Do you use this exact function? If yes, then you just overwrite the default in the first line, why would it work?

Comment: I have an if statement to check it and the high score works for the entirety of each simulator session. However, when either the simulator is closed or I simply run the program again, the previously set highscore (from the previous session) is no longer the highscore

Comment: just load it at viewDidLoad  highScore = defaults.doubleForKey("highScore")

Comment: @LeoDabus that was the issue, and adding the statement there worked. My apologies for everyone who tried to help, I attempted to simplify my code when I provided it but in the question there were errors but thank you all for the help!

Comment: @Jamman00 I have updated that answer and I thought you might be interested. I have also added a Double answer version to the question